# Can't change the theme of notifications after packages upgrade

Tags: xfce, theme, notifications

I'm under xfce4.16 and after a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`, the notifications theme has changed by itself.
In the notification settings, the theme is still Default.   If I try to change this theme by another one, nothing is taken into account.
Previously, notifications appeared black text on white background, the volume was a slider, not the percentage.

Below is the "new" theme:

[image: New notification theme]

Below the list of installed packages :

```bsh
2021-02-12 10:52:12 status half-installed mdadm:amd64 4.1-10
2021-02-12 10:52:12 status half-installed libcom-err2:amd64 1.45.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:12 status installed libcom-err2:amd64 1.46.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:12 status half-installed libprocps8:amd64 2:3.3.17-1
2021-02-12 10:52:13 status half-installed procps:amd64 2:3.3.17-1
2021-02-12 10:52:13 status half-installed reportbug:all 7.10.1
2021-02-12 10:52:13 status half-installed python3-reportbug:all 7.10.1
2021-02-12 10:52:13 status half-installed ant-optional:all 1.10.9-2
2021-02-12 10:52:14 status half-installed ant:all 1.10.9-2
2021-02-12 10:52:14 status half-installed code:amd64 1.52.1-1608136922
2021-02-12 10:52:22 status half-installed dsniff:amd64 2.4b1+debian-29
2021-02-12 10:52:22 status half-installed libglib2.0-dev:amd64 2.66.6-2
2021-02-12 10:52:23 status half-installed libglib2.0-dev-bin:amd64 2.66.6-2
2021-02-12 10:52:23 status half-installed libglib2.0-data:all 2.66.6-2
2021-02-12 10:52:23 status half-installed libglib2.0-bin:amd64 2.66.6-2
2021-02-12 10:52:23 status half-installed libglib2.0-0:amd64 2.66.6-2
2021-02-12 10:52:23 status half-installed libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 2.30.4-1
2021-02-12 10:52:25 status half-installed libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 2.30.4-1
2021-02-12 10:52:25 status half-installed gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 2.30.4-1
2021-02-12 10:52:25 status half-installed gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 2.30.4-1
2021-02-12 10:52:26 status half-installed network-manager:amd64 1.28.0-2+b1
2021-02-12 10:52:26 status half-installed libnm0:amd64 1.28.0-2+b1
2021-02-12 10:52:26 status half-installed gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 1.28.0-2+b1
2021-02-12 10:52:26 status half-installed libcodemodel-java:all 2.6+jaxb2.3.0.1-9
2021-02-12 10:52:26 status half-installed libdtd-parser-java:all 1.2~svn20110404-1.1
2021-02-12 10:52:27 status half-installed libfluidsynth2:amd64 2.1.6-1
2021-02-12 10:52:27 status half-installed libgraphene-1.0-0:amd64 1.10.2-1
2021-02-12 10:52:27 status half-installed libplexus-cipher-java:all 1.8-1
2021-02-12 10:52:27 status half-installed libmaven3-core-java:all 3.6.3-4
2021-02-12 10:52:27 status half-installed libmaxminddb0:amd64 1.5.0-2
2021-02-12 10:52:27 status half-installed libpq5:amd64 13.1-1+b1
2021-02-12 10:52:28 status half-installed librngom-java:all 2.3.0.1-9
2021-02-12 10:52:28 status half-installed libsnmp30:amd64 5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u1
2021-02-12 10:52:28 status half-installed libss2:amd64 1.45.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:28 status half-installed libsvn1:amd64 1.14.0-3+b2
2021-02-12 10:52:28 status half-installed libsvn-perl:amd64 1.14.0-3+b2
2021-02-12 10:52:29 status half-installed libxsom-java:all 2.3.0.1-9
2021-02-12 10:52:29 status half-installed libtxw2-java:all 2.3.0.1-9
2021-02-12 10:52:29 status half-installed libwacom2:amd64 1.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:29 status half-installed libwacom-common:all 1.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:29 status half-installed libwacom-bin:amd64 1.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:29 status half-installed libwsutil9:amd64 2.6.8-1.1
2021-02-12 10:52:30 status half-installed libwiretap8:amd64 2.6.8-1.1
2021-02-12 10:52:30 status half-installed libwscodecs2:amd64 2.6.8-1.1
2021-02-12 10:52:30 status half-installed libwireshark11:amd64 2.6.8-1.1
2021-02-12 10:52:31 status half-installed mythes-en-us:all 1:7.1.0~rc3-2
2021-02-12 10:52:32 status half-installed mythes-fr:all 1:7.1.0~rc3-2
2021-02-12 10:52:32 status half-installed network-manager-gnome:amd64 1.20.0-1
2021-02-12 10:52:32 status half-installed python3-cryptography:amd64 3.3.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:32 status half-installed python3-soupsieve:all 2.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status half-installed remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-1
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status half-installed remmina-plugin-vnc:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-1
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status half-installed remmina-plugin-secret:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-1
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status half-installed remmina:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-1
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status half-installed remmina-common:all 1.4.11+dfsg-1
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status half-installed screen:amd64 4.8.0-3
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status triggers-pending install-info:amd64 6.7.0.dfsg.2-6
2021-02-12 10:52:33 status half-installed xdg-desktop-portal:amd64 1.8.0-2
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed code:amd64 1.53.2-1613044664
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libdtd-parser-java:all 1.2-1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed gawk:amd64 1:5.1.0-1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libglib2.0-0:amd64 2.66.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libmaxminddb0:amd64 1.5.0-3
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libwsutil9:amd64 2.6.20-0+deb10u1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed remmina-common:all 1.4.11+dfsg-2
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libpq5:amd64 13.2-1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 2.30.5-1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed screen:amd64 4.8.0-5
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed mythes-en-us:all 1:7.1.0~rc3-3
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed dsniff:amd64 2.4b1+debian-30
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0:amd64 2.30.5-1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libplexus-cipher-java:all 1.8-2
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libsnmp30:amd64 5.7.3+dfsg-5+deb10u2
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed libglib2.0-data:all 2.66.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:41 status installed remmina:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-2
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed python3-cryptography:amd64 3.3.2-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libwiretap8:amd64 2.6.20-0+deb10u1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libss2:amd64 1.46.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed ant:all 1.10.9-3
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed remmina-plugin-rdp:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-2
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libnm0:amd64 1.29.90-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed logsave:amd64 1.46.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libcodemodel-java:all 2.6+jaxb2.3.0.1-10
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed librngom-java:all 2.3.0.1-10
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37:amd64 2.30.5-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed remmina-plugin-vnc:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-2
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libwscodecs2:amd64 2.6.20-0+deb10u1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed mythes-fr:all 1:7.1.0~rc3-3
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libxsom-java:all 2.3.0.1-10
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed python3-reportbug:all 7.10.2
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed gir1.2-nm-1.0:amd64 1.29.90-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libsvn1:amd64 1.14.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libfluidsynth2:amd64 2.1.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libtxw2-java:all 2.3.0.1-10
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed python3-soupsieve:all 2.2-1
2021-02-12 10:52:42 status installed libprocps8:amd64 2:3.3.17-2
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed mdadm:amd64 4.1-11
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed libgraphene-1.0-0:amd64 1.10.4+dfsg1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed libwireshark11:amd64 2.6.20-0+deb10u1
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed libwacom-common:all 1.8-1
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed libglib2.0-dev-bin:amd64 2.66.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed libsvn-perl:amd64 1.14.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed gir1.2-webkit2-4.0:amd64 2.30.5-1
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed xdg-desktop-portal:amd64 1.8.0-3
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed libmaven3-core-java:all 3.6.3-5
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed remmina-plugin-secret:amd64 1.4.11+dfsg-2
2021-02-12 10:52:47 status installed libglib2.0-bin:amd64 2.66.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:48 status installed e2fsprogs:amd64 1.46.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:48 status installed network-manager:amd64 1.29.90-1
2021-02-12 10:52:48 status installed reportbug:all 7.10.2
2021-02-12 10:52:48 status installed ant-optional:all 1.10.9-3
2021-02-12 10:52:48 status installed libglib2.0-dev:amd64 2.66.7-1
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed libwacom2:amd64 1.8-1
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed network-manager-gnome:amd64 1.20.0-2
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed e2fsprogs-l10n:all 1.46.1-1
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed libwacom-bin:amd64 1.8-1
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed procps:amd64 2:3.3.17-2
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed menu:amd64 2.1.48
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed mailcap:all 3.68
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed bamfdaemon:amd64 0.5.4-2
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed desktop-file-utils:amd64 0.26-1
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed hicolor-icon-theme:all 0.17-2
2021-02-12 10:52:49 status installed libc-bin:amd64 2.31-9
2021-02-12 10:52:52 status installed man-db:amd64 2.9.4-1
2021-02-12 10:52:52 status installed dbus:amd64 1.12.20-1
2021-02-12 10:52:54 status installed shared-mime-info:amd64 2.0-1
2021-02-12 10:52:55 status installed udev:amd64 247.3-1
2021-02-12 10:52:55 trigproc install-info:amd64 6.7.0.dfsg.2-6 <none>
2021-02-12 10:52:55 status half-configured install-info:amd64 6.7.0.dfsg.2-6
2021-02-12 10:52:55 status installed install-info:amd64 6.7.0.dfsg.2-6
2021-02-12 10:53:02 status installed initramfs-tools:all 0.139
```

I think another programm is taking over xfce4-notifyd.

If someone can help me

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried `xfce4-notifyd-config`?

Comment: It looks like a `dunst` package. Try to remove it. [link](https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=23433)

Comment: @BlueManCZ yes I tried `xfce4-notifyd-config` but it doesn't chnage anything

Comment: @BlueManCZ Ok thanks ! It was the `dunst` package that change the notification theme
I just remove and purge it and reboot, and now it's the default notification theme is back !
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It was the dunst package that changed the notification theme. I just removed and purged it and rebooted, and now the default notification theme is back. I referred to
https://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=23433 for the steps:

```
sudo aptitude remove --purge dunst && sudo reboot
```